# Add objects to Arraylist and use it outside method

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist

I have a question. I cant solve it and I need some help please. I have an Arraylist of objects then I have a method where objects are created and added to the Arraylist but I want another method where I can print the Arraylist but everytime I try the Arraylist is empty so this is my code:

```
public class Packages{
   ArrayList<Pack> myList = new ArrayList<Pack>();
   Pack obj;

   public double addPackage(int type, double num){
      if(type==1)
      {
         obj = new Pack(type, num);
         total = obj.calculateTotal;
      }
      else
      {
         obj = new Pack(type, num);
         total = obj.calculateTotal;
      }
      myList.add(obj);
      return total;
   }
   public int listSize(){
      return myList.size();
   }
}
```

Everytime I call the listSize() method it returns 0, looks like when the addPackage method finishes it deletes the objects I added to my Arraylist.
Note: my addPackage method is going to return a double total but at the same time add the objects I create to the arraylist. I need some help please.

Comment: Show where you're calling both methods.

Comment: Also, do you realize that the if and the else do exactly the same thing? Why is obj a field? It should be a local variable.

Comment: Your code, or at least what's shown, will work fine, though it's a bit odd, since I assume `calculateTotal` should be a method, not a property, `obj` should be a local variable, your if/else is totally redundant, etc.

Comment: Pack is another class and calculateTotal is a method from the Pack class. and addPackage and listSize methods are being called in a driver class. calculateTotal just returns the num + something else. type variable can be 1 or 2.

Comment: Though the code does not compile I have taken the liberty to make some changes and now it seems to work.

Comment: I have not made any performance enhancement or anything like that. I have made only minimum changes and you can improvise the code later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it is almost right. I am posting the classes again which I used and which work:

```
public class Package {
    List<Pack> myList = new ArrayList<Pack>();
    Pack obj;
    double total = 0;

    public double addPackage(int type, double num) {
        if (type == 1) {
            obj = new Pack(type, num);
            total = obj.calculateTotal();
        } else {
            obj = new Pack(type, num);
            total = obj.calculateTotal();
        }
        myList.add(obj);
        return total;
    }

    public int listSize() {
        return myList.size();
    }
}
```

Now class Pack is:

```
public class Pack {
    int type;
    double value;

    public Pack(int type, double value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double calculateTotal() {
        return type*value;
    }
}
```

And I verified in this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Package pkg = new Package();
        pkg.addPackage(10,10);
        pkg.addPackage(10,20);
        System.out.println(pkg.listSize());

    }
```

And as expected it returns `2`. All these classes may not exactly be same as what you have but it will give you the idea about what are you missing.

Comment: you gave me an idea I think the problem is in my driver class. what if I have a GUI class and I add the data just like you did, but instead I use 2 Jtextfields and a button to addpackage(which calls addPackage method) and another button to print the arraysize(which calls listSize method) do you thing everytime I click addpackage button it resets the previous data??

Comment: If those two buttons invoke method on same instance of `Package` then it should work provided code is written correctly.

Comment: it works now thank you!! I was creating the Package object inside the buttonlistener that was my mistake. it was so simple...